# How can I find standard rates for promo use of press photography?

Tags: pricing, licensing

A few months ago I did a series of photoshoots of authors at a literary convention, as a (stringer) press photographer for a minor online publication. Yesterday the agent of one of the subjects I shot got in touch with me, wanting permission to use images from one of the shoots for marketing/promotion/&c.

This use of my work is completely new to me (I've done some wedding photography, and sold some prints, but nothing else). It's a quite successful author and a major (European) publisher, so I'm loath to just not charge, but I don't have any point of comparison *at all* to base a rate on.

What is a range of rates people have used in the past for this sort of thing?

Comment: It probably highly depends on where you are. In Canada for example, CAPIC publishes standard rates for such things depending on size, publication numbers and distribution area.

Comment: @Itai The CAPIC guidelines are *exactly* what I was looking for. I'm not in Canada, but just having those published, standard rates as a reference point is enough information for me to set reasonable rates. Please write that up as an answer I can accept, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This greatly depends on your location.*

In Canada, the Canadian Association Of Professional Image Creators ([CAPIC](http://www.capic.org/)) published and regularly updates a document which describe suggested fees for various type of licences. You can find the 20-page PDF document [here](http://www.capic.org/resources-for-professional-photographers-and-illustrators) by clicking on the *Reproduction Fee* link.

This document shows the complexity of licencing images with fees varying for various use of images, publication numbers and distribution area whicn in Canada is counted by provinces.

There is nothing that prevents anyone for selling at a different price but the document helps establish baseline prices. That way, if a prospective client complains about price being too high, one can always point them to the document for support.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best videos I wached is Mark Wallace and Adorama video, describing in details how much your work costs. You can watch video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZj16RmtFeg).